# Solve: $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - \frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble attempting to solve this ode:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - \frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}$$

I tried to make a change of variables putting $xy = v$, but this led me to nowhere, since the solution I got didn't work when I replaced it in the original edo.

Besides, I am not so sure if the kind of change of variables I made is allow in the process of solving a particular edo.

So please, would anybody be kind enough to enlighten my understanding and help me to solve this edo? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The substitution you used should work, I obtained the following separable ODE:
$$v'=\frac{v^2-1}{x}$$
The resulting integral in $v$ can be done using partial fractions, and the integral in $x$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Make the substitution $$y(x)=-\frac{v'(x)}{v(x)}$$ the we get
$$x^2v''+xv'-v=0$$ assuming $$v(x)=x^{\lambda}$$ then we get
$$v=\frac{C_1}{x}+C_2x$$ and our solution is
$$y(x)=\frac{C_1-C_2x^2}{C_1x+C_2x^3}$$

Comment: You can divide top and bottom by $C_1$ if it is not zero. Then there is only one constant.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for your nice hint!

Comment: Also it should say $x^3$ on the bottom not $x^2$

Comment: wao. Thanks a lot. But, please, tell me how do you guess that change of variable ?? and I have another question: one can do any nonlinear or linear change of variable to make the ode as easy as one want to??

Comment: @Aldebaran : This is one typical solution strategy for Riccati equations. In the middle it is used that the equation for $v$ is of Euler-Cauchy type.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Start by multiplying both sides by $x^{2}$:
\begin{align*}
& y^{\prime} = y^{2} - \frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{x^{2}} \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y^{\prime} + xy + 1 = x^{2}y^{2} \Longleftrightarrow\\\\
& x(xy^{\prime} + y) + 1 = (xy)^{2} \Longleftrightarrow x(xy)^{\prime} + 1 = (xy)^{2}
\end{align*}

Then you make the substitution $w = xy$, from whence we get the ODE $xw^{\prime} + 1 = w^{2}$, which is a separable DE. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot. So, one can do any nonlinear or linear change of variable to make the edo as easy as one want to??

Comment: Not always, it depends on the ODE.

Comment: how?? Can you, please, address me to a web page, book or paper to understand that relation ??

Comment: Wikipedia is good enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Theories

Answer (score 0):

I just guessed with $y=a x^n$. Then to get $n$ the same power on the RHS we find $n=-1$. So we try $y=\frac{a}{x}$. Substituting this in we get:

$$y = \pm \frac{1}{x}$$

are two solutions. There maybe more.